# Monkey patching instance in Go

Tags: go, monkeypatching

I have structure with some fields inside and I Marshall that structure and return `json to client`. I `cannot change json nor structure` but in some corner cases I have to add one more additional flag. Is possible `instance monkey patching` in Go and how to achieve that ?
I can solve this through inheritance but I would love to see if dynamically adding property to instance of structure is possible in Go.

Answer (score 4):

No, you can't monkeypatch things like that in Go. Structs are defined at compile time, you can't add fields at runtime.

> I can solve this through inheritance (…)

No you can't because there is no inheritance in Go. You can solve it through *composition:*

```
type FooWithFlag struct {
    Foo
    Flag bool
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can always define a custom [`Marshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Marshaler) / [`Unmarshaler`](http://golang.org/pkg/encoding/json/#Unmarshaler) interface and handle it in your type:

```
type X struct {
    b bool
}

func (x *X) MarshalJSON() ([]byte, error) {
    out := map[string]interface{}{
        "b": x.b,
    }
    if x.b {
        out["other-custom-field"] = "42"
    }
    return json.Marshal(out)
}

func (x *X) UnmarshalJSON(b []byte) (err error) {
    var m map[string]interface{}
    if err = json.Unmarshal(b, &m); err != nil {
        return
    }
    x.b, _ = m["b"].(bool)
    if x.b {
        if v, ok := m["other-custom-field"].(string); ok {
            log.Printf("got a super secret value: %s", v)
        }
    }
    return
}
```

[<kbd>playground</kbd>](http://play.golang.org/p/vtp6Ajk7Jr)

Answer (score 0):

you could also use the `json:",omitempty"` option on your flag

an example:

http://play.golang.org/p/ebmZLR8DLj